# Integration test for Tornado server

Tags: python, integration-testing, tornado

I am coming from Java background and absolutely new at Python.

Suppose I have Python program `hello.py` that launches a web server like that:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop

def start_server(port, handler):
    app = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", handler), ])
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.bind(port)
    server.start(0)  # autodetect number of cores and fork a process for each
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello!")

start_server(5000, MyHandler)
```

Now I'd like to write an integration test for this server in Python. The test should:

- run `hello.py` to start the server
- send an HTTP GET request to URL `http://localhost:5000/hello` synchronously
- check if the response == `"Hello!"`
- stop the server

How would you suggest write such a test ?

Comment: It seems you want something like this example, no?
 http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look at the [`test`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/tornado/test) directory of [`tornado`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado). It contains all the `tornado` tests, that you can launch with `python` or `nosetests`.

You can have a look at [`httpserver_test.py`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/test/httpserver_test.py).

Comment: Well ... there is a lot of stuff there but I didn't find a test I need :( Maybe I am missing something. I need something _very_ simple. I want to write a Python script, which runs my server in a separate thread and talk to the server over HTTP. Is it doable in Python ?